# PHP Variable Issue

Tags: php, html

For starters, I am completely new to PHP.  That being said, here's my problem.

I've got a web page index.php that includes a header.php and footer.php.  At the top of my index.php page I have:

```
<?php $pageID = 'home'; ?>
```

In the header.php file I have

```
<body id="<?php echo $pageID; ?>">
```

Yet when the page loads, the body tag simply looks as follows: `<body id="">`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to show more code. Technically speaking, there is "nothing" wrong with that as long as the $pageID was set before you tried to echo it and was not set in a function which would not work due to SCOPE issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure that you're declaring `$pageID` **before** you include `header.php`. If you're not doing that, `header.php` won't get your `$pageID` variable's value as your index file would only be setting it after the file is included, so it prints nothing instead.

In terms of code, check that the order of those respective commands is this:

```
$pageID = 'home';
// anything else that might be in between
include 'header.php';
```

As opposed to this:

```
include 'header.php';
// anything else that might be in between
$pageID = 'home';
```

Comment: Ahh.  Obvious.  Thanks for taking the time to answer such a simple question.  I'll check this as answered once the page lets me...